# Special character in log/txt file not showing

Tags: text, unicode, encoding, hex, ascii

So i made a c# application to read my account and password (that is stored in plain text) inside another application.
It returns my password correctly, but my account / username is completely messed up.

I tried make my .log file UNICODE and it all turned into chinese letters. So it wasn't anything wrong there.

Anyone know how to change `?c <SOH>` into read-able letters? I dont know what that type of encoding is. ?C and ...... what is that? And it's a "long" blank space between them too. The ending of the account name is correct. but there is 2 characters in beginning that dont read.

I will try paste it here, if it works.
`?c in77`

here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: So you are sure that your file is encoded in Unicode? Which encoding exactly? `utf-8`? If that is

Comment: No it's in normal.. It's a normal .log file. And it show me this. And when I try switch it to Unicode (in hopes of seeing the characters), it all turn into Chinese. So I dont know what those characters are. ?c SOH is supposed to be 2 letters. @洋葱头

Comment: "normal" is not an encoding ;-) With [this](http://www.editpadlite.com/download.html) editor you can explicitly save a document in a certain encoding. I would suggest saving it in `utf-16`, which is also used by C# internally.

Comment: Saving with another encoding will not change the control character into something else. Are you sure the name is not encrypted? It would be strange though that the name would be encrypted, but not the password.